# Remote access to MySQL server in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows-7, mysql-workbench

Using MySQL Workbench in Windows 7 how can I bind my MySQL Server to my IP Address instead of 127.0.0.1 and how can I give users from different hosts access to it?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/09/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-server-on-windows/):

> 1. Open a DOS command prompt on the server.
> 2. Run the following command from the mysql\bin directory:
>
>    mysql -u root --password=
> 3. A mysql prompt should be displayed.
> 4. To create a remote user account with root privileges, run the following commands:
>
>    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'USERNAME'@'IP'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'PASSWORD';

Comment: Thanks! How can I change the binding though?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on hosting server on which the database is hosted e.g. by Hostgator hosting you may bind IPs to access the database remotely, you will have to provide access to user IPs in the hosting. For other like Go Daddy it depends on while creating the database, you will have to select for remote database option which generated a url likewise a host with which database can be accessed with SQLYog/Workbench.
My Answer is you can't bound the IPs with database tools but only with hosting servers.